# jQuery appending li from form. Help li disapears after .click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple text input that allows users to add items to an unordered list. The code is adding the new li (list item) but then it quickly disappears... Why!? I would like it to stay visible so the user can continue to add additional items and always see the list as it forms.

Live example at: http://jonathangrover.com/test.html

Code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add to list item on click</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        //set value as empty text string
        var value = ""

        //when clicking the submit button run the function
        $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
            //store value of text input
            var value = $('input[type=text]').val();
            //create a new li with the value of the input text inside
            $("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
        });

    });

</script>
</head>

<body style="margin:20px;">
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <form>
        <input type="text" />&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your form is submitting the page, returning it to its default state.

Instead of adding a `click` handler to the submit button, add a `submit` handler to the form and return false to stop it submitting:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
        //store value of text input
        var value = $('input[type=text]').val();
        //create a new li with the value of the input text inside
        $("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
        return false;
    });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5qcnH/

Answer (score 1):

This is because it is actually submitting the form and refreshing the page.

just return false to the click event in prevent the default action...

```
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        //store value of text input
        var value = $('input[type=text]').val();
        //create a new li with the value of the input text inside
        $("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Np make sure to mark correct and upvote if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return false` from the click handler to prevent the page from submitting, or change `<input type="submit"/>` to `<input type="button"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to

```
return false
```

to prevent default action (submit)

```
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        //store value of text input
        var value = $('input[type=text]').val();
        //create a new li with the value of the input text inside
        $("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
        return false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the form tag to `<form action="return false;">` then it should work.
Currently, you are submitting the form, and this refreshes it.

Alternatively, don't make it a submit, but rather just a normal button (and then I think you won't even need the form tags).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is posting back and reloading the page.  Try returning false.

Answer (score 0):

Because without `return false`, or equivalents, the form is submitting. Without a defined action for the `form` this reloads the current page.

Amended code:

```
//set value as empty text string
var value = ""

//when clicking the submit button run the function
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    //store value of text input
    var value = $('input[type=text]').val();
    //create a new li with the value of the input text inside
    $("ul").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/duLdQ/).

Or you could use `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`:

```
//set value as empty text string
var value = ""

//when clicking the submit button run the function
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //store value of text input
    var value = $('input[type=text]').val();
    //create a new li with the value of the input text inside
    $("ul").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/duLdQ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Your current code submits and therefore reloads the page.

Change the `<input type="submit">` to `<input type="button">`.